# Cannot run Django's FastCGI with pidfile option

Tags: python, django, fastcgi

I would like to run my Django sitw with FastCGI.

I can successfully start the TCP server with the following command.

```
python manage.py runfcgi method=prefork host=127.0.0.1 \
       port=3000 maxrequests=100 daemonize=true
```

However, if fails if I add the pidfile option in the command.

```
python manage.py runfcgi method=prefork host=127.0.0.1 \
       port=3000 maxrequests=100 daemonize=true pidfile=/var/run/django.pid
```

I got no exception printed out with the second command, but the TCP server is not started.

Django version: 1.6.11

May I know what could be the problem cause this failure?

---

I guess the failure might be caused by permission issue. I am running the command with a standard user. However, it does not solve the problem if I am using `sudo`.

---

Thanks for Andriy's answer, I have solved the problem. The TCP server is not started because of permission. However, by simply executing the command with `sudo` will not work.

Moreover, I did try using `django.pid` as the pidfile name. However, it seems that the script does not correctly resolve relative path. After changing the pidfile to a folder where current user have permission to write into with absolute path, it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, you has **no permisson** to create pidfile within `/var/run/django.pid`.

You can change [chmod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod) of `/var/run`, with command

```
sudo chmod -R 666 /var/run
```

or place **pidfile** under folder where you have write permissions, for example.

```
python manage.py runfcgi method=prefork host=127.0.0.1 \
   port=3000 maxrequests=100 daemonize=true pidfile=$HOME/django.pid
```